# parsing a String in PHP

Tags: php, string, parsing, codeigniter, uploadify

i got a string in the following format:

```
a:5:{s:21:"securimage_code_value";s:4:"4l7z";s:6:"userID";s:2:"25";s:8:"username";s:6:"lupoxy";s:10:"angemeldet";s:4:"true";s:9:"user_role";s:3:"111";}
```

I need to parse the entries within the quotes, and get an Array like this:

```
$testarray[0]['key'] = "securimage_code_value";
$testarray[0]['value'] = "417z";

$testarray[1]['key'] = "userID";
$testarray[1]['value'] = "25";
```

and so on...

No I'm not trying to hack any sessions ;) I'm using Uploadify with Codeigniter, and I need to verify, that a user is allowed to upload, based on his session. I cannot use the Codeigniter session functions, since Uploadify creates its own session for the Upload-PHP-Script. So I pass the session_id as Uploadify scriptdata, and then I look for the session_id in the ci_sessions table, to parse the required session userdata myself.

Maybe somebody knows a better solution for this as well? ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$params = unserialize($string);

$testarray = array();
foreach($params as $key => $value) {
   $testarray[]= compact('key', 'value');
}
```

See [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) documentation.

---

**UPDATE.** You could also inherit/patch `sess_read()` from system/libraries/Session.php to make it accept custom session ID:

Before:

```
function sess_read() {
  ...
  // Unserialize the session array
  $session = $this->_unserialize($session);
  ...
}
```

After:

```
function sess_read($session_id = null) {
  ...
  // Unserialize the session array
  $session = $this->_unserialize($session);
  if ($session_id) $session['session_id'] = $session_id;
  ...
}
```

Also remember to set `sess_match_useragent = false` in session config file, otherwise request from Uploadify will be rejected, because Flash's user agent is different from broswer's user agent.

And now you can load any session by ID:

```
$this->session->sess_read($custom_session_id)
```

Much less of a hack than parsing data from DB manually.

Comment: got it working...thank you so much! Im not that experienced in PHP yet, and I kinda got lost doing all this session stuff, your post helped me a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for `unserialize()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Answer (score 1):

the complet code

```
<?php

$s = 'a:5:{s:21:"securimage_code_value";s:4:"4l7z";s:6:"userID";s:2:"25";s:8:"username";s:6:"lupoxy";s:10:"angemeldet";s:4:"true";s:9:"user_role";s:3:"111";}';

$final = array();
foreach (unserialize($s) as $k => $v) {
    $final[] = array('key' => $k, 'value' => $v);
} 

var_dump($final);
```